# Insert a code, click on a button and extract the result with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I state that I have never used Scrapy (and therefore I do not even know if it is the right tool).

On the website https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/, I am interested in entering an 11-digit numeric code (for example 06655971007) in the bar "INSERISCI LA PARTITA IVA/RAGIONE SOCIALE" and then click on "CERCA". Then I would like to save the resulting HTML in a variable that I would later analyze with BeautifulSoup (I shouldn't have any problems with that).
So, how can I do the first part?

I imagine something like:

```
import scrapy

class Extraction(scrapy.Spider):

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/"
        # To enter data
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url, formdata={...}, callback=self.parse)
        # To click the button
        # some code

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

These are the HTML of the search bar and the button:

```
<input type="search" name="search_input" class="autocomplete form-control" onchange="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; checkPartitaIva()" onkeyup="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; checkPartitaIva()" id="search_input" placeholder=" " value="">

<button onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; dataLayer.push({'event': 'trova azienda'});" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-uppercase">Cerca</button>
```

Comment: first you could use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see how browser sends data when you press button. You should show what fields it send, with what values, etc. And later you can use it in `formdata={ }`. Problem can be if it uses `JavaScript` to calculate some values because `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript` and you would use `scrapy` with `Selenium` - module `scrapy-selenium` - or you could write all only with `Selenium` (without `scrapy`)

Comment: `scrapy` has own functions to analyze HTML so it doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: If I use `formdata={"search_input": "06655971007"}` nothing happens (I don't even get an error). Could you please provide an example script for the two instructions (11-digit numeric code insertion and button click)?

Comment: did you check requests in `DevTools` ? I saw many other values - like `g-recaptcha-response`, `token`, etc. and you have to send all these values. You have to find then im HTML. So first you have to load page using GET, and later send POST.

Comment: maybe better use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of `scrapy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses JavaScript to generate some elements so it would be simpler to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url =  'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)  # JavaScript needs time to load code

item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//input[@id="search_input"]')
#item = driver.find_element_by_id('search_input')
item.send_keys('06655971007')

time.sleep(1)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//p//button[@type="submit"]')
button.click()

time.sleep(5)  # JavaScript needs time to load code

item = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
print(item.text)
print('---')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')
for item in all_items:
    if '@' in item.text:
        print(item.text, '<<< found email:', item.text.split(' ')[1])
    else:
        print(item.text)
print('---')
```

Result:

```
DATI DELLA SOCIETÀ - ENEL ENERGIA S.P.A.
---
Partita IVA: 06655971007 - Codice Fiscale: 06655971007
Rag. Sociale: ENEL ENERGIA S.P.A.
Indirizzo: VIALE REGINA MARGHERITA 125 - 00198 - ROMA
Rea: 1150724
PEC: enelenergia@pec.enel.it <<< found email: enelenergia@pec.enel.it
Fatturato: € 13.032.695.000,00 (2020)
ACQUISTA BILANCIO
Dipendenti : 1666 (2021)
---
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But how can I print the content of the field "email", starting from the resulting HTML? Printing the HTML directly would also be ok, then I would go and look directly for the "email" field in the text.

Comment: if you means `PEC: enelenergia@pec.enel.it` then you can use xpath `//ul[@id="first-group"]/li` to get all items as list and later you can use Python to search item with  `@` or with `PEC:` and get only `email` . I added this to code. And I added result which I get.

Comment: and if you want full `HTML`  then you have it in `driver.page_source`

Comment: Perfect, your answer helps me a lot. I see the website recognizes that a scraper is working after just a few calls. There is no internal way in Python to avoid this, right?

Comment: it had to say what server checks to detect it. Maybe server checks time between requests and it should run slower and make random delays like real human. Maybe server checks `User-Agent` and it should use full `User-Agent` from real web browser. Selenium use JavaScript to get data and maybe server check in there are added some functions or variables - and this would need to compile Selenium with different settings - and you can find this in some other question.

Comment: I see. Last thing: how do i prevent a new Firefox window from opening every time I launch the script?

Comment: selenium has to use new browser to control it. But you can use option `headless` to run without displaying window. Details you have to search in other questions.